# Windows x64 stack frame ABI shenanigans

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, stack-frame

so I am making a toy compiler to assembly and my program is failing at the boundary of my generated code and C code. This is what the assembly looks like:

```
(Pseudo-code from my compiler)
def test(x: int) -> int:
    return magic_func(magic_func(x, x), magic_func(x, x))
(Actual output assembly:)
test:
push rcx
mov rdx, rcx
call magic_func
mov rdx, rax
pop rcx
push rdx
mov rdx, rcx
call magic_func
mov rcx, rax
pop rdx
call magic_func
ret
```

The C code looks like this:

```c
int magic_func(int x, int y) {
    printf("magic_func(%d, %d)\n", x, y);
    return x + y * 2;
}
extern int test(int);
int main() {
    printf("%d\n", test(44));
    return 0;
}
```

And the `magic_func` function specifically like this: (from objdump)

```
push   rbp
mov    rbp,rsp
sub    rsp,0x20
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp+0x10],ecx
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp+0x18],edx
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x18]
mov    r8d,eax
mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x10]
lea    rcx,[rip+0x0]        # 1e <magic_func+0x1e>
call   23 <magic_func+0x23>
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x18]
lea    edx,[rax+rax*1]
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x10]
add    eax,edx
add    rsp,0x20
pop    rbp
ret
```

Now, I've found out with GDB that the segmentation fault occurs at the `ret` instruction of my function (`test`), but always at the third (final) invocation. The return address that was supposed to be saved on the stack is rewritten with some garbage. I'm sure this is some Windows stack shenanigans with alignment or some red zones or me not allocating enough space but I can't figure it out. Somebody with Windows calling convention experience who could give me a tip?

Comment: Notice how a debug build of `magic_func` spills its incoming stack args to its shadow (above its return address).  This is overwrites your function's (`test`'s) return address because you didn't reserve shadow space for the callee.  Notice how the compiler-generated code for `magic_func` reserves 0x20 bytes in addition to aligning the stack with a `push`, before calling `printf`.  (You're looking at disassembly of a `.obj`, not an asm listing or disassembly of a linked executable, so `call +0`  is just a placeholder, like with the RIP-relative LEA into RCX)